# Return all max values in xquery

Tags: xml, max, xquery

I Created the following xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE Movies SYSTEM "actressinfo.dtd">
<ActressInfo>
<Actress firstname="Robin" lastname="Nico" count="7"/>
<Actress firstname="some" lastname="chick" count="7"/>
<Actress firstname="random" lastname="chick" count="6"/>

</ActressInfo>
```

And I want to retrieve all values that are equal to max count in xquery

```
for $p in doc("actressinfo.xml") //ActressInfo
where $p/Actress/@count = max($p/Actress/@count)
return  $p/Actress/@count
```

However this returns everything, why is it doing so? Despite the value returned by max being correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're iterating over `ActressInfo` so `$p/Actress/@count` will return all `Actress` counts from every `ActressInfo`. If you want the highest count `Actress` for each `ActressInfo`:

```
for $p in doc("actressinfo.xml")//ActressInfo/Actress
where $p/@count = max($p/ancestor::ActressInfo/Actress/@count)
return $p
```

Or for all `Actress` elements matching the overall maximum:

```
let $max := max(doc("actressinfo.xml")//ActressInfo/Actress/@count)
for $p in doc("actressinfo.xml")//ActressInfo/Actress
where $p/@count = $max
return $p
```

If you only have one `ActressInfo` element, then this makes more sense. If there are multiple, and you want one `Actress` per `ActressInfo`, then the first query is probably a better fit.